# appending character array to string c++

Tags: c++, string

I have a character array of 256 characters or `char myArray[256]` only the first couple actually hold any information

```
myArray[0] = 'H';
myArray[1] = 'E';
myArray[2] = 'L';
myArray[3] = 'L';
myArray[4] = 'O';
myArray[5] = NULL;
myArray[6] = NULL;
// etc...
```

I won't necessarily know exactly what is in the array, but I want to copy what is there, minus the null characters, to my buffer string `string buffer`

I thought the appropriate way to do this would be by doing the following:

```
buffer.append(myArray);
```

And the program would stop reading values once it encountered a nul character, but I'm not seeing that behavior. I'm seeing it copy the entirety of the array into my buffer, null characters and all.  What would be the correct way to do this?

Edit: Some working code to make it easier

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string buffer;
    char mychararray[256] = {NULL};

    mychararray[0] = 'H';
    mychararray[1] = 'e';
    mychararray[2] = 'l';
    mychararray[3] = 'l';
    mychararray[4] = 'o';

    buffer.append(mychararray);

    cout << buffer << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Just realized I wasn't initializing the null properly and my original way works. Sorry to waste yall's time.

Comment: Your "working code" is completely different. You're missing the `=NULL` part. Which is it?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, will all values of `mychararray` after index 4 not be `NULL` by default (this is an actual question, I'm quite inexperienced at c++)?

Comment: @usernametbd no - if you want them to be 0, set them to 0 yourself explicitly, or just do: char mychararray[256] = { 0 };

Comment: You're code (up top, with nulls) should work - see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/ ... How does 'append' know the size of `mychararray`?

Comment: Your code should work once you add null termination ([link](http://ideone.com/679CsL)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with

```
buffer += myArray;
```

should do it. `append` should also work if you null-terminate the array.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the work:

```
int c;
while(myArray[c] != NULL) {
  buffer.append(1,myArray[c]);
  ++c;
}
```

Also, you should do something like this: `myArray[5] = '\0'`

Comment: `=NULL` and `='\0'` are equivalent.

Comment: He didn't initialize the array, that's why he should put that.